# What is the best method for account verification in a local country?

Tags: user-behavior

I am building a Mobile Application that will be active for Lebanon country only. It is related to car renting. The user has to verify his account. The process will be easy for the citizens inside the country, but what should i do for the users outside Lebanon and wish to rent a car before they arrive so the car will be delivered to the airport? how can i avoid the spammed registration through e-mail account verification?

Comment: It sounds like you're not preventing anyone renting a car, what's the purpose of verifying they are from Lebanon?

Comment: Have you asked the rental car company which documents they require for overseas customers? Assume this would be a good starting block, if they currently rent to tourists offline.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make the payment through Credit Card is better solution, because you could get the real information of them to verify their identity and make sure they have the money to pay the rent.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the car rental application require user to submit their driving documents over before their account created. Only when the approval got verified by your team, then they can proceed with booking of vehicle.

As for spammer, you might want to read this post up

[CAPTCHA on mobile: what are the alternatives?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51864/captcha-on-mobile-what-are-the-alternatives)